# Importing CommonJS modules to an ESM syntax

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I'm struggling to understand how to import CommonJS modules into an ESM syntax. I'm currently trying to work with the library `url-metadata`. `url-metadata` exposes a top-level export as a callable (which does not really conform to CommonJS, AFAIK):

```
const urlMetadata = require('url-metadata')
urlMetadata(URL, ...)
```

It's not possible to write:

```
import urlMetadata from 'urlMetadata'
```

since no default export is defined.

Instead, I have to write:

```
import * as urlMetadata from 'url-metadata'
```

Or:

```
import urlMetadata = require("url-metadata")
```

I tried to read up on module loading in Node but I'm still somewhat confused as to what is the correct way to do this and why.

Comment: did you [read all of this](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v15.x/api/esm.html#esm_introduction)?

Comment: The question doesn't make sense in general. "since no default export is defined" - this isn't true, cjs exports are conventionally translated to default esm, unless your setup makes it work differently.  "import urlMetadata = require("url-metadata")" - this isn't valid JS. In case you use TS, the question should be rewritten to reflect this.

Comment: What is wrong with `import * as urlMetadata from 'url-metadata'` to import a CommonJS module from an ESM module?

Comment: Maybe my problem is that I'm using TS and not grasping the concept correctly. Importing as default `import urlMetadata from ...` produces this error: `TypeError: (0 , url_metadata_1.default) is not a function`. While `import * as urlMetadata ...` works fine. I don't understand why that is.

Comment: Ok, I think this question is very hard to answer since I'm struggling too much with the different concepts to ask in a coherent form. I've since figured out that I had forgotten to set the `esModuleInterOp` flag for the Typescript compiler. Without this flag `module.exports` is not set as the default export and the type error was produced. By doing `import * as ...` the entire exotic `exports` object was loaded which also worked but is arguably not the best way to do this.

Answer (score 11):

```js
import urlMetadata from 'url-metadata';
```

is syntactic sugar for

```js
import { default as urlMetadata } from 'url-metadata';
```

Either will work fine.

The value assigned to `module.exports` in a CommonJS module is the default export.

See the [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v17.x/api/esm.html#esm_commonjs_namespaces) docs.